# "Advanced" Ubuntu links

Tags: ubuntu-netbook

I have an intermediate baseline experience with the Linux OS/features and functions in general. That is I understand commands like cat/grep etc and know what a BASH shell is.

I am a software developer by trade (Win OS but I understand Programming language concepts) so I am familiar with code files etc.

I have been using Ubuntu (Maverick) lately for a legacy MacBook which I can speedily do daily tasks such as ask questions on askubuntu and check emails.

What I am looking for is to go some levels deeper into what makes up the Ubuntu OS.  Some examples of things I would like to look at are:

- The finer details of the Gnome UI (and GTK) - which files "drive" the UI and control at a granular level.
- More in depth details about how drivers and libraries work together to allow all of my peripherals to work seamlessly when plugged in.

In essence I am looking for a reference that is not how to log-in, update themes, install apps/sources etc.

I am looking for a level deeper.

Google is providing me with too much information and I have not come across a suitable reference.

What good electronic resources are available (eg links, ebooks) which will be suitable for a "post" beginner which you have found useful?

Answer (score 1):

[Read about Debian](http://www.debian.org/doc/), the Linux distribution on which Ubuntu is based. Debian is meant for more advanced users, so the information you'll find will be more in-depth.

Comment: Thanks for the link. This contents list has a large number of interesting topics: http://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/debian-reference/

Comment: As a side-note is Ubuntu based on debian (as in no longer part of debian) or are debian updates still pushed up to ubuntu?

Comment: Ubuntu was never actually part of Debian, it is a separate project that uses parts of Debian. AFAIK Ubuntu has maintained separate package repositories since shipping the first version. No debian updates are "pushed" to Ubuntu, but some are "pulled" by the Ubuntu package maintainers.